# bootloader boot loop

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop, bootloader

I got a new Pixel 2 and wanted to load an TWRP backup from my previous Pixel 2 (with stock ROM) onto it, instead of setting it up freshly. So I

- booted the new device
- clicked through the settings
- entered developer mode and oem unlock
- rebooted
- unlocked the bootloader
- booted into TWRP (using `fastboot boot`)
- copied my old `/sdcard` contents to the device using `adb`
- used TWRP to restore the old backup (partitions `boot`, `system` and `data`.

At that point I hoped I was done, and could just boot into my system. But unfortunately, it always just boots into the bootloader.

What did I do wrong?

And what do I do now?

- I tried to do a factory reset by using `fastboot flashing lock`, and it claimed it would reset the phone, but it doesn’t.
- I tried to enter recovery from the bootloader, but it just boots into the bootloader.
- I tried to flash an official image from https://developers.google.com/android/images#walleye using `./flash-all.sh` but it fails to update the bootloader:

  ```
  Sending 'bootloader_a' (38692 KB)                  OKAY [0.155s]
  Writing 'bootloader_a'                             (bootloader) Updating: partition:0   @00002000 sz=0000B000
  FAILED (remote: 'Command Flash Error')
  fastboot: error: Command failed
  ```

  and then fails do do more:

  ```
  --------------------------------------------
  Bootloader Version...: mw8998-002.0059.00
  Baseband Version.....: g8998-00008-1902121845
  Serial Number........: …
  --------------------------------------------
  extracting android-info.txt (0 MB) to RAM...
  Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [0.000s]
  Checking 'version-bootloader'                      FAILED

  Device version-bootloader is 'mw8998-002.0059.00'.
  Update requires 'mw8998-002.0076.00'.

  fastboot: error: requirements not met!
  ```
- I tried to boot twrp again, but that does not work:

  ```
  $ fastboot boot twrp-3.3.0-0-walleye.img 
  downloading 'boot.img'...
  OKAY [  0.115s]
  booting...
  FAILED (remote: Failed to load/authenticate boot image: Load Error)
  ```

What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script at https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-2-xl/development/tool-deuces-bootloop-recovery-flashing-t3704761 was able to apply a system update.